# Converting 1 to 10000 , into 00001 to 10000 , decimal to string

Tags: php

I have an array of 1 to 10000 just want to know how can I convert the value of 1 into 00001 , 2 into 00002 , and so on..

Is there a php code for this, that works like this?

```
<?php
for ( $x = 1; $x <= 10000; $x++ ) {
$numbers[$x] = php_function_here( $x ); // convert 1 to 00001 , 5 decimals
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/str_pad

Answer (score 4):

```
$numbers[$x] = sprintf("%05d", $x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf: http://php.net/function.sprintf

```
for ( $x = 1; $x <= 1000; $x++ ) {
   $numbers[$x] = sprintf('%05d', $x ); // convert 1 to 00001 , 5 decimals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way to do it using `str_pad` and `range` :

```
$max_number    = 10000;
$number_length = strlen($max_number);
$numbers = array_map(function($number)
{
    return str_pad($number, $GLOBALS['number_length'], "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, range(1, $max_number));
```